# How to run an application in /opt?

Tags: application-development, qt, qt-creator

I want to know how one can run his application in /opt and installed in /opt. I want it for the ubuntu app showdown
http://developer.ubuntu.com/showdown/

I will be using qt with qt creator and c++; will qt and qt creator automatically install in /opt?

Do most frameworks by default install in `/opt`?

A few more questions:

- Will qt take advantage of unity?
- ok, qt is cross platform with maintaining the platform uniqueness, it integrates with ubuntu so are there libraries for c++ to for unity and are they easy to use and install
  http://unity.ubuntu.com some we can find here?
- Can I have plugins for that app, and will plugin will make good sense to improve the app? Basically plugins like unity lenses and that integrates in ubuntu. I will put them in Ubuntu software center but i will use quickly to create them, so will they affect my project, will judges see that?
- So as I understand, every application submitted to ubuntu software center will be considered for competition or do I have to mark them?

Comment: Please create a separate Askubuntu question for every question, otherwise it's impossible to answer.

Comment: i am sorry but when i ask question in different questionbs then your site says "it doesn.t meet our quality standards" you site never excpects small questions

Comment: AskUbuntu works only if you submit one question per question, which is what most users do. If your question is too small, please simply ellaborate it more to meet the standards. If you need help creating a question, I would recommend reading the FAQ at http://askubuntu.com/faq - thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the comment, please ask one AskUbuntu question per question.

I'll answer the first two:

> I will be using qt with qt creator and c++; will qt and qt creator automatically install in /opt?

It will not unless you instruct it too through your build system. I assume you'll be using cmake or autotools as a build system, so you'll have to create extra rules for the installation to /opt.

This is one of the reasons we recommend Quickly, as it will handle the packaging and installation to /opt transparently for you.

> Do most frameworks by default install in /opt?

They don't. Most apps are packaged with a build system and the packaging layer on top. The default parameters for build systems in Debian and Ubuntu machines are to install to `/usr/share`. Installation to /opt is a requirement for all third-party applications that are submitted through the app developer process.